Is Windows (Network) Folder Size accurate?
We have a program that adds columns to various Excel files daily. One way we try to track that it is working is checking the overall folder size and seeing if it increases. The numbers however do not seem to add up.
As a test, we start with folder Size 14,873,776,616 and Size on disk 14,876,917,760 bytes.
I go to a random Excel file with Size 9,189,791 and Size on disk 9,191,424 bytes.
I add 75 rows to it. This changes it to Size 9,192,219 and Size on disk 9,195,520 bytes.
But, the folder size remains exactly the same.
I'm trying to find some kind of source that folders or network folders don't necessarily have the size completely accurate, but all I have is what I'm seeing in front of me.
Is anyone able to shed light on how accurate the folder size is supposed to be?
Edit: Changed question from "Is Windows (Network) Folder Size inaccurate?" to "Is Windows (Network) Folder Size accurate?".
If I don't see a yes, I'll let my team know we got zero yes answers, that no one is willing to vouch for this.

"I add 75 rows to it." .. more details might be helpful.  Like how are you adding the rows?  Are you exiting EXCEL completely and ensuring that the disk is flushed before checking the size?  That size you see MIGHT be in the temp folder until synced.  That size you see MIGHT be in memory only.. and even then, it could be compressed.  Please elaborate on the process.


Size on a file system is based on the allocation unit size, https://www.howtogeek.com/136078/what-should-i-set-the-allocation-unit-size-to-when-formatting/. if unit size if 4kB, file with 1 byte and with 3,000 bytes both consume 1 a.u., 4 kB. 2. MS Office files are compressed; adding a few kB of text or data might increase size by only a few bytes.


@Señor CMasMas I add text to rows that were previously empty, then save and close Excel completely.

@DrMoishe Pippik I would love to see a difference of a few bytes in the folder size, but I am seeing a folder size of exactly 14,876,917,760 bytes before and 14,876,917,760 bytes after

@Koops128, Again, that is perfectly reasonable. If the allocation unit (AU) is 4 kB, and a file takes 100 x 4 kB + 1 byte, it uses 101 AU. If the file is 100 x 4 kB + 3,900 bytes, it still uses 101 AU. Looking from the outside at a file's size tells very little about how storage is used inside. While it's likely file size would change when adding rows, there's no guarantee it would change. Look at date modified, or use a tool to diff files, e.g., https://www.windowscentral.com/how-compare-two-files-command-prompt-windows-10 . You could use a batch program to check for differences.
